# How to get the current user logged in my AspNet project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-framework-version

I created a simple AspNet project (.net framework) and after the successful login I'm in the HomePage.

If I click on the "Hello mail@mail.it!" button I can access the Manage method and get my current **User.Identity.Name** (that would be my mail@mail.it) because my **UserManger** and **SignInManager** are populated.
Instead if I try to access another method in an ApiController and retrieve the User.Identity.Name, the 
UserManger and SignInManager are empty an my name is *null*.

That's my ApiController:

```
namespace NameSpace.Controllers.API
{     
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public LoginController()
        {
        }


        public LoginController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _signInManager = value;
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); 
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Check()
        {
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            if(username != null){
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, username );
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Is there something I'm missing or there is another away to find the current user?

Comment: What about HttpContext.User?

Comment: @mesies that's where the `User` property comes from. If it's null, it means the request was anonymous

Comment: If `User` is null, the request was anonymous. Login forms are shown when the user is *not* logged in, so there's no reason to assume `Use` will be anything but null. `Check` method shouldn't even compile. by the way. `.Name` is a string, not a boolean. `a` isn't defined.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah I modified the code while I was copying too. I changed the code now

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the following:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Update:

try the following to get http context:

```
// get httpContext here

object httpContext;
actionContext.Request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out httpContext);
```

Comment: The if returns null cause it says there is no user authenticated. But if i can do that  in a get/post request in a controller and the return value is the Name, why cant i do it in an ApiController?

Comment: see if you can get httpcontext by using the updated code above and then try to retrieve the username and userId.

Comment: Nope, still empty fields. I think at this point , as @PanagiotisKanavos pointed out, the call is missing the authentication and if i dont pass the Bearer to authorize the call, it will not populate the User